# In $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, let $I =\{f (x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \mid f (0) = 0\}$. Prove that $I = \langle x \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> In $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients, let $I:=\{f (x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \mid f (0) = 0\}$. Prove that $I = \langle x \mathrm\rangle$ and $I$ is not a maximal ideal.

---

Can anyone help me please how can I able to solve this problem?

Comment: If you need to put a `{` in $\LaTeX$, you can write `\{`.

Comment: Use [polynomial remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show $I \subseteq (x)$ and $(x) \subseteq I$.

Of course, for $f(x)=x$, $f(0) = 0$ hence for all $p(x) \in (x) = (f(x))$ it holds that $p(0) = 0$ since $p$ is of the form $q(x)f(x)$ for some $q(x) \in \mathbb Z [x]$. Therefore $(x) \subseteq I$.

On the other hand, let $p(x) \in I$. Then $p(0) = 0$. Apply that for every zero $n$ of $p$, you can write $p(x) = (x-n)q(x)$. Then $p(x) = xq(x)$. Hence $p \in I$.

To see that $(x)$ is not maximal note that $(x,2)$ is a proper ideal properly containing $(x)$.

Comment: thanks.how can I show that it is not a maximal ideal.

Comment: @priti Oh right, I didn't see the second part of your question! Let me add it.

Comment: @priti Okay, added it! : )

Comment: @priti My pleasure! : )

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\rm\:\ f\in I\stackrel{def}\iff f(0)=0\iff x\mid f\iff f\in \langle x\rangle$

If $\rm\,\langle x\rangle\,$ were maximal then $\rm\:\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x\rangle \cong \Bbb Z\:$ would be a field.

Answer (score 2):

$I$ is not maximal, because $\frac{Z[x]}{(x)}\cong Z$ and $Z$ is not a field.